# does numpy.where change all values parallelly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
              value           some other cond

0              0                      true
1              1                      true
2              0                      true
3              1                      true
4              1                      true
5              0                      false
```

so I want to apply this changes to the 'value' column:

IF previous rows value was zero AND some other cond was true THEN change current rows value to zero OTHERWISE leave it be.

First I tried vectorizing with np.where like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["value"] = np.where((df["value].shift(1) == 0) & (df"Some Other Cond" == "true",
    0, df["value"])
```

and it changed the values to this:

```
              value          new value

0              0                0

1              1                -> 0 ( Correct)

2              0                0

3              1                -> 0 ( Correct)

4              1                -> 1 ( Unchanged! even though it should change to 0)

5              0                0
```

as you can see, numpy.where method kinda applies on all cells PARALLELLY. it doesnt start from uptop, and then come down the rows one by one, doesnt work like that. and thus, it doesnt work like how I expected.

so I was forced to loop through whole 'value' column to apply the changes I wanted. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    if (df.at[i - 1, 'value'] == 0) and (df.at[i, 'Some other cond'] == 'true'):
        df.at[i, 'value'] = 0
```

so this DID solve my problem, but obviously, its TOO slow to loop through whole dataframe. adding this loop to my code, increased my run time length from 10 seconds to 2 minutes! almost 12x.

so my question is:

How Should I do this without a for loop? is it possible at all?

if not, how can i speed up my loop?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I used Tim Roberts Answer and used np.apply. reduced runtime from 120 seconds to 35 seconds. around 4x faster.

Comment: In `df["value"] = np.where((df["value].shift(1) == 0) & (df"Some Other Cond" == "true", 0, df["value"])` there is a missing closing `"` character for the string `value` as the value of the `df` array.

I imagine this is just a typo from copying the code to StackOverflow, but I thought I'd point it out. :)

Comment: yes that was a typo. sorry for that. thank you my friend

Comment: If this row's new value depends on the NEW value of the previous row, then it cant be parallelized.  You have a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a separate flag variable in your code that is set to true when a value is changed to 0, and false when a value is not changed. That way you can check the flag instead of the previous value, which may or may not have changed yet.

Comment: You don't really mean "have had time to change yet".  The change takes place immediately.  You're still talking about going row by row, so it's not going to be much faster than what he has.

Comment: I did this. still same wrong result.

Comment: @TimRoberts You're right, I don't really mean that. I assumed you would understand that I was talking about completion of the task on a parallel thread as opposed to purely how long the individual task's computation takes. I will edit out the word "time" so that other readers will not misunderstand as well.

Also, I was not intending to advise the asker on how to speed up the program. I was answering the original question posed, "How Should I do this without a for loop? is it possible at all?"

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you ask.  It's still an iterative operation, but at least you're allowing numpy to do the iteration instead of a Python loop.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  [ 0, True ],
  [ 1, True ],
  [ 0, True ],
  [ 1, True ],
  [ 1, True ],
  [ 0, False ],
  [ 1, False ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value','cond'])
print(df)

last = 1
def process(row):
    global last
    last = (not row['cond'] or last) and row['value']
    return last

df['newvalue'] = df.apply(process, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   value   cond
0      0   True
1      1   True
2      0   True
3      1   True
4      1   True
5      0  False
6      1  False
   value   cond  newvalue
0      0   True         0
1      1   True         0
2      0   True         0
3      1   True         0
4      1   True         0
5      0  False         0
6      1  False         1
```

### Followup

Here is the truth table of your three inputs:

| value | cond | last | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | true | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | true | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | true | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | true | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | false | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | false | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | false | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | false | 1 | 1 |

What we see here is that when `cond` is false, we just echo the input `value`.  When `cond` is true, the result is `value AND last`.  That produces the following expression:

```
last = row['value'] if not row['cond'] else row['value'] and last
```

That was my first approach, and it worked.  What I put in the script is just a rearrangement that eliminates the repeated value.

Comment: `apply` is basically a python level for-loop. It is certainly not a numpy-level thing (although I believe in recent pandas versions, it's been cythonized). Honestly, a regular loop will probably be better

Comment: It Worked! Reduced runtime from 120 seconds to 35 seconds. around 4x faster! Thank you!!! but can you explain the logic a little bit? Im a noob and I didnt understand how the code worked. thanks my friend!

Comment: I built a truth table from your three inputs, which are the `value`, the `cond`, and the last row written.  When `cond` is false, you always want the `value`.  When `cond` is true, you want the logical AND of `value` and the previous row -- if either of them are 0, the result is 0.  That produces the expression within the function.  I'll add the truth table.

Comment: What was my codes problem? its simply not possible to use np.where in this situation?

Comment: No, it's not.  You cannot use a single expression here because of the dependency.  There is no use of `where` that looks at the OUTPUT from the previous row.